# Scrolling is not working after close simplemodal popup

Tags: jquery, scroll, mousewheel, simplemodal

I am using simplemodal popup. I have some items in the popup to select. On selecting the the items i will close the popup using jquery. After that scrolling is not working but the scroll bar is there. I have used the below code to close the popup. The below function is called to close the popup.

```
function setSlotTime(time, slotDuration, isReload){
    selectedTime = time;
    duration = slotDuration;
    $(".simplemodal-close").click();

    if(userId.trim() != ''){
        $( "#content-frame").contents().find("#datepicker").val(selectedTime.split(" ")[0]);
        $( "#content-frame").contents().find("#datetimepicker").val(selectedTime.split(" ")[1]+" "+selectedTime.split(" ")[2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your modal is closing?

Comment: Did you try to use the close() method instead of the click event on the close button ? Do you have an error in the js console ?

Comment: I have tried close() function also. But still i am facing the same issue. Also there is no error in the console.